# OpenGL ES tutorial for android doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I've been following the tutorial at http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es20.html for OpenGL ES on android. I've gotten to the, "Apply Projection and Camera View" section however I always seem to get a blank screen with no triangle, the previous section worked perfectly fine. I also tried just copy pasting the entire tutorial into my code but got the same result. Changing the line:

```
gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;
```

to:

```
gl_Position = vPosition;
```

puts the application back to the first section (triangle stretches depending on screen orientation). Any idea what the problem is? Here's the code I have so far just in case I missed something:

```
public class GLTest20Renderer implements Renderer {
    private final String vertexShaderCode = 
        // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
        // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;   \n" +

        "attribute vec4 vPosition;  \n" +
        "void main(){               \n" +

        // the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
        " gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition; \n" +

        "}  \n";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode = 
        "precision mediump float;  \n" +
        "void main(){              \n" +
        " gl_FragColor = vec4 (0.63671875, 0.76953125, 0.22265625, 1.0); \n" +
        "}                         \n";


    private FloatBuffer triangleVB;

    private int mProgram;
    private int maPositionHandle;

    private int muMVPMatrixHandle;
    private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mMMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mVMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mProjMatrix = new float[16];

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);

        initShapes();

        int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL Program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // creates OpenGL program executables

        // get handle to the vertex shader's vPosition member
        maPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
        GLES20.glClear( GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

        // Add program to OpenGL environment
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        // Prepare the triangle data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 12, triangleVB);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);

        // Apply a ModelView Projection transformation
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);

        // Draw the triangle
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        float ratio = (float) width / height;

        Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);

        muMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
        Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    private void initShapes() {
        float triangleCoords[] = {
            // X, Y, Z
            -0.5f, -0.25f, 0,
             0.5f, -0.25f, 0,
             0.0f,  0.559016994f, 0
        }; 

        // initialize vertex Buffer for triangle  
        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
                triangleCoords.length * 4); 
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());// use the device hardware's native byte order
        triangleVB = vbb.asFloatBuffer();  // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
        triangleVB.put(triangleCoords);    // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
        triangleVB.position(0);            // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
    }

    private int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode) {
        // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type); 

        // add the source code to the shader and compile it
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

        return shader;
    }
}
```

I'm running all this on a Samsung Galaxy S2.

Comment: Well, I managed to fix it by changing the near point in the look at to 2: Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 2, 7); rather than 3, not sure if this is an error on their part or if I still missed something.

Comment: are you sure if the device supports opengl2.0?

Comment: Yep, I've run OpenGL2.0 applications on it before

Comment: The sdk sample for this in api 15 worked for me. Maybe you could compare code to know what happened.

Comment: In the example, it appears they are placing the triangle directly on the near clipping plane. Maybe your devices implementation of the clipping stage clips stuff directly on the plane as opposed to letting it stay. Try setting the near plane to something like 2.98 or 2.99 and see what happens.

Comment: I think you're right, that seemed to work for me.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a common problem. Perhaps it's device specific?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fixed, just changed the near point in the lookat to be under 3:

```
Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 2, 7);
```

Comment: But why its like that ? I have tested on Galaxy Note 3/Galaxy S3/Galaxy S Advance. Only on Note 3 example works without modifications. Any Ideas ?